# Black background-color after html element

Tags: html, css, background-color

I am having an issue on my website with the background color. The code between the html tags works perfectly fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
//...
</html>
```

To get the desired result. HOWEVER, if the screen is too big to hold the bage, a black background color appears at the bottom to take up that space:

[image]

Everything works fine if the page is equal to or bigger than the screen. No overflow of the black area happens.

**NOTE:** If I zoom out of any of the pages to the point where the Screen is bigger than all the content, all the pages will have the same issue.

**QUESTION:** Is there a way in CSS (or Javascript) to change the default color of the black area in the picture (which resides after the HTML element)?

---

Edited:

The following website is an example:
https://www.phpbb.com/styles/demo/3.1/board/index.php?style=1246

if you scroll back from the website, and use google chromes "inspect" option, you'll see that the html is not taking up the whole page, and that the black part at the bottom is something separate. I would like to know how to change that blackness at the bottom into another color (like white).

Comment: Why you don't use ``height:100%;`` and ``width:100%;`` on html and body to adjust the visible area to the screen size?

Comment: Please create a demo that can actually show the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you see your live example once with active `background-color` rule on `body` and without. And you see it's the `body`'s `background-color` what causes the black.

**Active**:
[image: Active Background-Color]

**Not active**:
[image: Not-Active Background-Color]

If you want to keep the `body` black, so set the `background-color` of your `html` tag to the color you wish (at the moment it's transparent, so it lets the black color of the body through).

[image: Set Background-Color on HTML]

For your desired white you would do something like:

```
html {
  background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

I don't know if you can change the default, but if not you can just add `!important` right after the color code.

Answer (score 0):

To get the background color all the same add:

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(153,153,153);
}
```

Comment: No this doesn't work, I have tried it already, both for body and html.

Comment: Body and html modify the "white" part of the picture above. That black part seems to not be influenced, even if I use an inline style which should override any other styles being applied.

Comment: I think as well this should work. I can't reproduce this behavior in any browser. The space outside of the html element will have the same color as the background-color of your html or body element. So please provide your code.

Comment: @ScientiaEtVeritas I added a like to a real life example of the situation. The previous method did not work. And to an extent it makes sense why it didn't work.. because for some reason, the part at the bottom is not being considered as inside the <html>...</html> element. The question is why?

Comment: it's hard to figure out a problem when you are not showing all the css and html code. Make a codepen http://codepen.io/# or jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ and link to that.